# airport express IPv6 issue?

Tags: macos, network, airport, ipv6

I'm considering that it can be an issue with airport express IPv6 but not sure, might be another unrelated thing which then I would like to know more about.

To put it simple I'll say the following: When I'm connected direct to university network then I can  access youtube but if I put airport express in between then I can't access youtube. I mean I setup apple airport express to connect via dhcp to university network and connect through it to university network.

I noticed differences in macOS network panel, here its connected directly:

[image]
[image]

And here its connected via airport:

[image]
[image]

Probably I should mention that I'm experiencing this in China, where youtube is blocked but for some unknown reason it works in the situation exposed before.

Anybody can explain what's going on?

Comment: Probably they have not blocked youtube on IPv6. But you can't get IPv6 behind the airport express unless your university provides DHCPv6 prefix delegation (and they likely do not).

Comment: What will be the advantages of leaving it unblocket just on IPv6?